# Converting a mongo stored date back into milliseconds since Unix epoch when loaded?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I am using Mongoose & Node.js for my webserver.

As a part of one of my document schemas, I have a 'timestamp' field.
The line for it in the schema is: 
`timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }`

This works fine, and allows me to retrieve documents based on the timestamp, however, this saves as the ISODate format as described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date, like this:

`"timestamp":"2013-04-04T19:31:38.514Z"`

I don't mind this, but I send this to the client as is. This means I have to use Date.parse() at the client end before I can comparative operations with it.

Is there any way to either store the date as an integer, or automatically convert it to one when it's retrieved?

Is there any reason I should keep it how it is, and just deal with it at the client end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add the numerical milliseconds version of `timestamp` as a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) attribute on the schema:

```
schema.virtual('timestamp_ms').get(function() {
  return this.timestamp.getTime();
});
```

Then you can enable the virtual field's inclusion in `toObject` calls on model instances via an option on your schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  timestamp: Date
}, {
  toObject: { getters: true }
});
```

Comment: ` {toObject: {virtuals: true}, toJSON: {virtuals: true}}` works for me

Comment: Hey but this adds a new field `timestamp_ms`, but what if I want the time stamp to be returned in the same field `timestamp`? How can that be done?

Answer (score 6):

```
var schema = new Schema({
  timestamp: {type:Number, default: new Date().getTime()}
});
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: You should not explicitly call a method for a default property because it gets the time of creation not insert. So, `Date.now` work very well.

Answer (score 4):

As a best practice, I would say: **keep your data the type it deserves**.

Anyway, if your client needs to treat with numbers, you can simply pass the date as milliseconds to the client, and still work with Date objects in Node.

Just call `timestamp.getTime()` and ta-da, you have your unix timestamp ready for the client.

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me

```
db.eurusd.ticks.findOne({_id:ObjectId("518636777055000000000000")}).t.getTime()
```

returns time in miliseconds, where returned document has structure

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("518636777055000000000000"),
 "t" : ISODate("2013-05-05T10:37:43Z"), // date data type
 "ask" : "Joe",
 "bid" : 33
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you set mongoose type as "Date" , mongoose convert timestamp to UTC, because timestamp is a number, not a Date. then if you want to store timestamp, you should set mongoose type as "Number".

```
myfield{
    type: Number,
    default: Date.now()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about getters?

```
  expiresAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    get: function (date: Date) {
      return date.getTime();
    },
  },
```