# MongoDB native Node.js driver server side insert timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timestamp, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I'm having problems with server-side insertion timestamp (in milliseconds) using MongoDB native Node.js driver.

I need server-side insertion timestamp in milliseconds because I will calculate the time between *requestTime* and *insertTime* to make same performance tests on different DBs.

My code is:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'); 
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');
var collection = db.get('usercollection');

collection.insert({
    "oName" : "objectName",
    "clientSideTimeInMilliseconds" : (new Date).getTime(),
    "serverSideTimeInMilliseconds": new mongo.Timestamp()
})
```

When I run this code and get back result, the output is:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("57299bef5624336f1d17be20"), 
  "oName" : "objectName", 
  "clientSideTimeInMilliseconds" : 1462344687114, 
  "serverSideTimeInMilliseconds" : Timestamp(1462344687, 1) 
}
```

*clientSideTimeInMilliseconds* variable is time with milliseconds however, *serverSideTimeInMilliseconds* variable is time only with seconds.

Comment: **[This might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15834666/2065039)**

Comment: How can I assign "serverSideTimeInMilliseconds" variable to this function on insert?

Comment: [_This type is for INTERNAL use in MongoDB only and should not be used in applications_](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Timestamp.html). Also, [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) seems to suggest that the (useful) resolution is 1 second.

Comment: I tried [your link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) before I posted here. `new mongo.Timestamp()` is working but  `new mongo.Date()` function is not exist. @robertklep

Comment: It is not for production. It is for testing purpose and I need server-side insertion timestamp where I don't care how it can be produced