# Change in date-time format after updating mongoose package

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My data document on Mongodb looks something like this -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6a2c118983c210d8ed66b7"),
    "team" : 1,
    "player" : ObjectId("5c68e63e8983c210d8ed66af"),
    "player_type" : "striker",
    "player_timestamp" : ISODate("2019-02-18T03:52:49.371Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

My data model looks like -

```
var playerSchema = new Schema({
  player: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
  team: {type: Number, required: true},
  player_type: {type: String, required: true},
  player_timestamp: {type: Date, required: true, get: function(value) {
    return value && moment(value).format('x');
  }},
}, {timestamps: true});
```

I have been using `mongoose 5.1.3` for a while and the date for player_timestamp gets returned in the epoch time format.

I recently upgraded to `mongoose 5.4.12` and noticed that the timestamp gets returned as `2019-02-18T03:52:49.392Z`.

How do I ensure that `mongoose 5.4.12` returns epoch time as before?

EDIT: I don't know why this got flagged as a duplicate just because it mentions epoch time and mongoose. It is quite different from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830733/converting-a-mongo-stored-date-back-into-milliseconds-since-unix-epoch-when-load) because this issue showed up only after I upgraded to the new version of mongoose. The new version of mongoose in question here (5.4.12) was released only 2 months ago and the question is almost 6 years old. So something broke/changed between 5.1.3 and 5.4.12. What is it that changed? How do I get back the behaviour from 5.1.3 without changing my code all over again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a mongo stored date back into milliseconds since Unix epoch when loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830733/converting-a-mongo-stored-date-back-into-milliseconds-since-unix-epoch-when-load)